# How to modify and implement transaction fees?

Tags: substrate-node-template, fee

So now that I can already capture the transaction_fees+tip and into the Author of the block.  I want to modify my transaction_fees so that I can charge for example 0.4% of whatever being transferred.

I debug the fees:

```
tokio-runtime-worker runtime::system: [18] length: 11 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight: 0 (0%) / op weight 0 (0%) / mandatory weight 5862211000 (0%)
```

Comment: Good question. Here is some supporting info for this question: [Transaction Payment pallet docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/pallet_transaction_payment/index.html) and [Transaction Payment pallet code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs).

Comment: Yes Mr. Burno, I went through the documents and can only convert the weights to the corresponding fees, these might do for now.  But I need the percentage of balance transferred to be be working for my use cases.

Comment: i am interested in this as well